# Python conflicts in RStuido

Tags: python, rstudio, reticulate

I am working on a markdown and wrote an R chunks in which I import reticulate and try to execute the listdir function but I have nothing but a mapply error.

After this I decided to execute the code line by line in the Rstudio console and they throw me a set of errors and in the end I think it can be the clue to the problem. You [can see the error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QENf2.png)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error shows that it can't find `python3` so first check if path is correct.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm stuck in a similar problem.